# How to get "chapter.1" on the left and "Chapter Title" on the right

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I'm using a template in TexStudio which has a defined set of *fancyhdr* rules. But I wants to change the layout of chapter header: make the chap.1 on the left and to put the chapter title onto the right side (see the attached image).

Is there any way I an overrule the defined settings? Because it's very long declarations under *fancyhdr.sty* file and I'm not sure which part to alter. [image: Header layout]

Comment: Yes, there is a way to do this.

Comment: However, it almost certainly has nothing to do with `fancyhdr` which concerns only headers and footers, neither of which are shown in the image you posted.

Comment: You can use `titlesec` to do that.

Comment: Cool! That's great. I thought I have to alter the _fancyhdr_.   I will do it by _titlesec_. Thanks @Bernard

Comment: Use the `display `style, `\filleft` for the label line, and `\filright` for the chapter  title line.

Comment: I am doing it the way you told. But when I use `\filleft` it actually comes on the right side :-P . Here is the code i'm using. `\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
   {\filleft\normalfont\Large}
   {\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}\ \thechapter}
   {20pt}
   {}`  As this one does not work, I didn't try the `\titlerule` yet.

Comment: I am doing it the way you told. But when I use `\filleft` it actually comes on the right side :-P . Here is the code i'm using. `\titleformat{\chapter}[display]   {\filleft\normalfont\Large {\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}\ \thechapter} {20pt}   {}`   As this one does not work, I didn't try the `\titlerule` yet. @Bernard

Comment: Sorry, I messed up `filleft` for the 2nd line and `filright` for the 1st line. I've posted an answer to show how to proceed. Hope this is more or less what you want.

Comment: Cool! Thanks @Bernard   It has worked for the chapter heading. But it has also changed the normal header to appear always on the _right_ side of the page.   They were previously toggling from page to page between left and right side appearance.

Comment: Do you mean the header on top of pages?  I didn't touch it. It's the  `book` class default. Of course this can be changed, with `fancyhdr` for instance, or `titleps`, which comes with titlesec, and is easier to use, in my opinion. What would you like to have? Default is chapter title on the left side on even pages, section titles on the right side on odd pages (no header on the first page of a chapter).

Comment: Yes, I can see it. We didn't touch `fancyhdr`. It's just because I was initially playing with with `fancyhdr` and it's okay now. Page headers are now appearing in a standard way which you have also mentioned. Thanks @Bernard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to to do it with `titlesec`. The `*` in `\titlespacing` suppresses indentation at the beginning of the chapter.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec, graphicx, geometry, titlecaps}

%Chapter Headers%
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{}{\normalfont\Large\scshape\titlecap{\chaptertitlename}\enspace\scalebox{1.8}{\thechapter}\filright} {8ex}{\Huge\bfseries\sffamily\filleft}[{\titlerule[1pt]}]
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{30pt}{20pt}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

[image]