# Chapter Section to the left and Chapter title to the right

Tags: titlesec, sectsty

In a report document, how can I achieve something like this?

[image]

The Chapter to the left, and the Chapter's title to the right of the page

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ragged2e} 
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[table,dvipsname]{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{minitoc} 
\usepackage{titlecaps}

%%%%%%%% FOR TESTING %%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%Initializing Minitoc
\dominitoc[n]
\nomtcpagenumbers

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{}{\normalfont\Large\scshape\titlecap{\chaptertitlename}\enspace\scalebox{1.8}{\thechapter}\filright} {8ex}{\Huge\bfseries\sffamily\filleft}[{\titlerule[1pt]}] 

\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{30pt}{20pt}

\begin{document}

    \tableofcontents


    \chapter{A}
    \label{Chap.A}

    \minitoc 

    \section{A.1}
    \label{A:sec:1}

    Wubba lubba dub dub.

    \section{A.2}
    \label{A:sec:2}
    \blindtext

    \newpage

    \chapter{B}
    \label{Chap.B}

    \minitoc 

    \section{B.1}
    \label{B:sec:1}
    \Blindtext

    \section{B.2}
    \label{B:sec:2}
    \blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: You are using the very right tags. Packages `titlesec` (more customizable) and `sectsty` (more simple) are for this purpose.

Comment: Here you can find an excellent answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/331805/how-to-get-chapter-1-on-the-left-and-chapter-title-on-the-right

Comment: W0099(minitoc(hints)) --- The titlesec package is loaded. (minitoc(hints)) It is incompatible (minitoc(hints)) with the minitoc package.

Comment: @JouleV I did. But I am new to the whole LaTeX world. I cannot understand the syntax of this function (?) \formattitle.

Comment: The only problem with your code is that `\titlecap` is not defined.

Comment: Okay so I updated the code but I have some questions if thats okay. Can you explain to me which part removes the Bottom horizontal line from the title? Also Can I modify the letter size and style? Lets say for example I wish to make it Bold or Underlined. How can I do this?

Comment: Remove `[{\titlerule[1pt]}]` to remove the line

Comment: Thank you for your time.

Comment: @Broxigar You have two answers. Please accept the one helping you most by clicking the checkmark on the left of the answer (you can't accept both).

Comment: Yes yes you'll get your credits! :P sorry I forgot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ragged2e} 
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[table,dvipsname]{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{minitoc} 
\usepackage{titlecaps}

%%%%%%%% FOR TESTING %%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%Initializing Minitoc
\dominitoc[n]
\nomtcpagenumbers

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{}{\normalfont\Large\scshape\bfseries\underline{\titlecap{\chaptertitlename}\enspace\scalebox{1.8}{\thechapter}\filright}} {8ex}{\Huge\bfseries\sffamily\filleft}

\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{30pt}{20pt}

\begin{document}

    \tableofcontents


    \chapter{A}
    \label{Chap.A}

    \minitoc 

    \section{A.1}
    \label{A:sec:1}

    Wubba lubba dub dub.

    \section{A.2}
    \label{A:sec:2}
    \blindtext

    \newpage

    \chapter{B}
    \label{Chap.B}

    \minitoc 

    \section{B.1}
    \label{B:sec:1}
    \Blindtext

    \section{B.2}
    \label{B:sec:2}
    \blindtext

\end{document}
```

- Removing `[{\titlerule[1pt]}]` will remove the line
- Just add additional commands `\underline` or `\bfseries` to make your text bold or underlined.

[image]